# How can i make a Button in android appear in a fixed position and always in front of all other views?

Tags: java, android, xml

I know the code might not be well formatted but I want the button (last tag) to always appear in front
 of all other views if the description is long the button disappears.
I'm using scrollView and if any long text appears but this makes the button go down the screen.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:id="@+id/cart_button"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:iconTint="@color/black"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:text="ADD TO CART"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceButton"
            android:textColor="#28022E"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:backgroundTint="#F6F2FA"
            app:elevation="10dp"
            app:rippleColor="#FFF"
            app:shapeAppearance="?attr/shapeAppearanceSmallComponent"
            app:strokeColor="#0000"
            app:strokeWidth="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: First image is with long description the second is what i want the result to be.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your button out of scrollview.
something like :

```
<RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    // content that you wants to scroll

   </ScrollView>

   <Button alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```